# Background-size: cover on hover zoom transition

Tags: html, css, background-size

I want to make zoom effect when user hover link (div) with image background.

I don't know how to do it when i want to zoom only background not text! And i cant find the best way.

Here is a code (doesn't work as i want):

```css
.light_blue {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
}
a.light_blue:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fcb428;
}
div.wrap {
  height: 33%;
  width: 33%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.wrap {
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -webkit-transition: all .8s;
  transition: all .8s;
  background-position: center center;
}
.wrap:hover {
  -webkit-background-size: 120%;
  -moz-background-size: 120%;
  -o-background-size: 120%;
  background-size: 120%;
}
.bg_flat {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Archivo Narrow";
  background: url(http://hokejfan.pl/hokej2015/kluby/img/black_bg4.png);
  background-size: contain;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.bg_naglowek {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 29px;
}
.bg_flat2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(../img/black_bg4.png);
  background-size: contain;
  font-family: "Archivo Narrow";
  bottom: 5px;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 10px);
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4" style="padding: 5px;">
  <a href="#news" class="light_blue wrap" style="background-image: url('http://hokejfan.pl/hokej2015/kluby/static/images2/48b51db749e3d9d992a61d289bc3c535.jpg'); height: 180px;">
    <div class="bg_flat2">
      <b class="bg_naglowek">Hello World</b>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 26):

You can't smoothly animate the `background-size` property if it's set to `cover`.  But you can fake it by animating `transform` instead.  And since you only want the image scaled, not the contents, you'll need a child element dedicated to displaying the image (done with a pseudo-element in the example below).

```css
.wrap {
  width: 33%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .8s;
  background: url(http://hokejfan.pl/hokej2015/kluby/static/images2/48b51db749e3d9d992a61d289bc3c535.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.wrap::before { 
  content:"";
  position:absolute; top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;
  background:inherit;
  transition:inherit;
}
.wrap:hover::before { 
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.content {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand how this works... but it does. Because the 'before' gets larger than the '.wrap', the background scales?

Comment: @CalvinBramlett exactly.  And notice the `background:inherit` rule applied to the ::before element, so it has the same background as .wrap, and scaled on hover by `transform: scale(1.2);`

Answer (score 2):

To animate the `background-size` property, you need to set it for the normal and the hover state. Then `transition` will work.

```css
.light_blue {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
}
a.light_blue:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fcb428;
}
div.wrap {
  height: 33%;
  width: 33%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.wrap {
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -webkit-transition: all .8s;
  transition: all .8s;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.wrap:hover {
  -webkit-background-size: 120%;
  -moz-background-size: 120%;
  -o-background-size: 120%;
  background-size: 120%;
}
.bg_flat {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Archivo Narrow";
  background: url(http://hokejfan.pl/hokej2015/kluby/img/black_bg4.png);
  background-size: contain;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.bg_naglowek {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 29px;
}
.bg_flat2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(../img/black_bg4.png);
  background-size: contain;
  font-family: "Archivo Narrow";
  bottom: 5px;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 10px);
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4" style="padding: 5px;">
  <a href="#news" class="light_blue wrap" style="background-image: url('http://hokejfan.pl/hokej2015/kluby/static/images2/48b51db749e3d9d992a61d289bc3c535.jpg'); height: 180px;">
    <div class="bg_flat2">
      <b class="bg_naglowek">Hello World</b>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: looks good, but i will use different size images, so it could be not natural if i use size 100% instead cover ?

Answer (score 0):

this the code actually for use zoom effect .. it depends on you to set the scale level.

```
wrap:hover {
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Comment: Sure, but it also scale my text "Hello World" and i dont want it. Only background, is it any way to do it:) ?

Comment: which div ?? It look like you set all the div inside anchor tag <a>

Comment: Yes, i want to make all (background image & text) clickable.Maybe other ways?

Comment: Ok so you want only the background to zoom not the text.  Let me try it.. but maybe I have to change the structure .

Comment: you want to make all clickable. But only the image will larger not the text. I do something like that but the problem is when you hover the text it will not give you the zoom effect for the background image. and everything is click able. and image will be your column size